# gdx-video - Error: Failed to resolve: com.badlogicgames.gdxvideo:gdx-video:0.0.1

Tags: android, video, libgdx

I would like to use `gdx-video` extension in my `libGDX` project, to embed a YouTube video. I have found this extension on GitHub, but there are several error messages during `Gradle` Sync process. I have pasted dependencies in `build.gradle` file.

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.badlogicgames.gdxvideo:gdx-video:0.0.1
>   Error:Failed to resolve:
>   com.badlogicgames.gdxvideo:gdx-video-platform:0.0.1 Error:Failed to
>   resolve: com.badlogicgames.gdxvideo:gdx-video-android:0.0.1

Comment: Show your gradle builds

Comment: These are error messages after Gradle build. Dependencies have copied from there: https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced your problem and here is a solution:

1) Make sure that `oss.sonatype.org` repositories are synchronized correctly. You can check it in `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Repositories` (I use Idea 15.0.3). If it's not - press Update button.On my machine it took about 40 minutes to sync releases and about 10 for snapshots.

2) Then in your root `build.gradle`:

```
        project(":core") {
           dependencies {
                    ...........
              compile "es.e-ucm.com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-video:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
          }
      }

        project(":android") {
            dependencies {
                compile project(":core")
                ..............
                compile "es.e-ucm.com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-video-android:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
            }
        }

        project(":desktop") {
            dependencies {
                .................
                compile "es.e-ucm.com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-video-desktop:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
            }
        }
```

Then resync project. I didn't use that project, so, if you miss some dependencies go to [sonatype.org](https://oss.sonatype.org/#welcome) and search for `gdx-video` (I saw `gdx-video-parent` and `gdx-video-gwt` project there also, not sure what they are responsible for)

Comment: There is no Maven option under Build Tools. There is only one option, Gradle.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio, the newest version.

Comment: Well, I guess now it works, doesn't it? Cos I saw a gdx-video specific question from you :)

Comment: Yeah, this part seems okay, but that you can see, there is blank screen yet on that class. :)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this inside of AndroidStudio by editing the build.gradle for the project and adding these dependencies to allprojects and buildscript. Make sure to use the updated names mentioned above.

```
compile "es.e-ucm.com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-video-android:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

compile "es.e-ucm.com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-video:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

---

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
}
```